# How to take two inputs in one line of m long list and int y

Tags: python, arrays

So I'm trying to intake `n` lines of `m` values and `y` for a multiple regression problem.

```
x = []
y = []
m, n = map(int,input().split())     
for i in range(n):
    x_val, y_val = #the code im looking for
    x.append(x_val)
    y.append(y_val)
```

The challenge I'm facing is that I want `x_val` to be a list of `m` length, and the last input of that line to be `y_val`, then append list `x_val` into `x` and `y_val` into list `y`!

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: x_val, y_val = what?

Comment: that`s the code I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpacking operator `*`

And probably if the user-input length is defined then you don't even need the `m` value.

```
x = []
y = []
m, n = map(int,input().split())     
for i in range(n):
    *x_val, y_val = map(int,input().split())
    x.append(x_val)
    y.append(y_val)
```

Notice the asterisk `*` in front of `x_val`

Unpacking `*` grabs everything left over after normal variables have been assigned

Input:

```
3 2
10 20 30 1
40 50 60 2
```

Output:

```
>>> x
[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]]
>>> y
[1, 2]
```